# Find out if old facebook access token was valid

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to find out if an expired access token was once a valid token for my app?

I'm using a token as a key for the user in a key/value store, and since it will eventually expire I'd like to find out if there is a way to determine if it was at once time a valid token for that user/app.

My one thought is to do a query with the expired access token, and check that the response is anything *but*

`{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating application.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190
   }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Try to plug in the access token in this url and do a GET

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If it works then the token is valid

Comment: Will that work for any valid access token or just the access tokens generated by the user making the client side request?

Comment: It looks like the error message will be different if the access token is from a different user

Comment: This is for the user token generated for each user. Just be careful when you use tokens, as they expire after some time like a day or two depending on the kind of access you asked form Facebook for the users.